# Convert Lon Lat to XY in Openlayers 3

Tags: geojson, openlayers, latitude-longitude, xy, vector-layer

I have a map which retrieves Points of Interest from a database and displays them however the Lon Lat need to be transformed into XY to be placed properly.
Currently the all just appear at O,O and I believe they have been transformed to decimal degrees.

I have tried using ol.proj.transform but this returns undefined. Do I have to create a calculation to convert these or is there a method to do this? 
The result of this function is returned to a vector layer which loads the features onto a map, albeit in the wrong position.

There are many examples using Openlayers 2 but the syntax is completely different. My non-working example is below:

```
/* Features conversion */
function wsToCollection(routeData) {

    //console.log(routeData);
    var fc = new Object;
    fc.type = "FeatureCollection";
    fc.features = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < routeData.Points.length; i++) {
        var feature = new Object;
        feature.type = "Feature";
        //console.log(feature);
        feature.geometry = new Object;
        feature.geometry.type = "Point";
        feature.geometry.coordinates = [];
        var Lon = routeData.Points[i].Longitude;
        //var LonTrans = ol.proj.transform(Lon, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'); // not working
        console.log(LonTrans);
        var Lat = routeData.Points[i].Latitude;
        //var LatTrans = Lat.transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'); // also not working
        feature.geometry.coordinates[0] = routeData.Points[i].Longitude;
        feature.geometry.coordinates[1] = routeData.Points[i].Latitude;
        feature.properties = new Object;
        feature.properties.name = routeData.Points[i].Description;
        feature.properties.Guid = routeData.Points[i].Guid;
        feature.properties.LongId = routeData.Points[i].LongId;
        fc.features.push(feature);
    }

    return fc;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you transform you always transform pair of points:

```
ol.proj.transform([23.4, 42.5], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857');
```

(this transforms from EPSG 4326 to EPSG 3857; the coordinates are [lon, lat])

Comment: Thanks so much @fidelfisch, I hadn't read that anywhere and stupidly I didn't think to try. That's working perfectly now. :)

Comment: Good to hear that's working. Enjoy the map :-)

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for this function too, and I have found it in some of the examples on their site.

You can use `ol.proj.fromLonLat([19.062072, 47.473478])`.

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/apidoc/ol.proj.html#.fromLonLat